# custom filtering of edittext in android

Tags: android, listview

I have created the edit text with custom filtering process.If i have typed any text the list gets filter based on the text.These are working fine.My problem is to hide the listview if click any 2nd item from the list.But the listview not hide instead.That clicked(2nd item list value)  is always visible.I have tried some like this.`

```
class Keyskilladapter extends BaseAdapter {


        private List<EmpModel> movieItems;

        ValueFilter valueFilter;
        Context mcontext;
        private List<EmpModel> mStringFilterList;

        TextView  designation,company;
        String val;
        public Keyskilladapter(Context mcontext, List<EmpModel> movieItems) {

            this.mcontext = mcontext;
            this.movieItems = movieItems;
            this.mStringFilterList = movieItems;
            this.mStringFilterList.addAll(movieItems);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return movieItems.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int location) {
            return movieItems.get(location);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.job_list,parent,false);
            }



            designation=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);


            final EmpModel m = movieItems.get(position);


            if (m.getsearchkey_skills() != null) {
                if (!m.getsearchkey_skills().equals("null")) {
                    designation.setText(m.getsearchkey_skills());
                }
            }
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                             val = (String) (m.getsearchkey_skills()) ;
                            searchkey.setText(val);
                            key_listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                        }
                    });


                }});


            return convertView;



        }
        public Filter getFilter() {
            if (valueFilter == null) {
                valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
            }
            return valueFilter;
        }

        private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                List<EmpModel> filterList = new ArrayList<EmpModel>();
                if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < mStringFilterList.size(); i++) {
                        if ((mStringFilterList.get(i).getsearchkey_skills().toUpperCase())
                                .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {

                            EmpModel m = mStringFilterList.get(i);
                            filterList.add(m);
                        }


                    }
                    results.count = filterList.size();
                    results.values = filterList;
                } else {
                    results.count = filterList.size();
                    results.values = filterList;
                }
                return results;

            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                          FilterResults results) {
                movieItems = (List<EmpModel>) results.values;

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }

        public void filter(String charText) {
            //  charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            movieItems.clear();
            if (charText.length() == 0) {
                movieItems.addAll(mStringFilterList);
            }
            else
            {
                for (EmpModel wp : mStringFilterList)
                {
                    if (wp.getsearchkey_skills().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))
                    {
                        movieItems.add(wp);
                    }
                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

searchkey.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                headline = s.toString();

                adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s, new Filter.FilterListener() {
                    public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
                        Log.d("log", "result count:" + count);
                        if(count==0){

                        }
                        else{

                            key_listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        }

                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


            }
        });
```

Comment: where did u initialize this key_listView ?

Comment: i have initialized inside the oncreate